# Fatal error in MailingEventForward.php

Tags: error, cron-job, civicrm-event

I have this error in the cron job log:
PHP Fatal error:  Duplicate declaration of static variable $fields in .../civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/Event/BAO/MailingEventForward.php on line 236
This is a CiviCRM on wordpress 5.68.0

Answer (score 0):

This will be fixed in 5.70. You can apply this patch: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/28838/files

Comment: Thank you a lot, Demerit